# Finding the closest point on a line to another point

Tags: java

I have a affine equation `y = ax + b` where a is the coefficient (`coeff`). 
Let D be a line that goes through `axis` and described by the previous equation.

I'm trying with this piece of code to find the coordinates of the closest point on D to `position` (ignoring the y coordinate, because 2D in 3D)

```
    double a = coeff;
    double b = position.getZ();
    double c = axis.getZ() - axis.getX() * coeff;
    double x0 = position.getX();
    double y0 = position.getZ();

    return new Vector((b * (b * x0 - a * y0) - a * c) / (a * a + b * b), position.getY(),
            (a * (-b * x0 + a * y0) - b * c) / (a * a + b * b));
```

Using [this as a refernece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)

However, this does not work and return weird results

Comment: How are you not getting a compile error? afaik `Vector` has no constructor for three arguments: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

Comment: What is "position" in your code?  Is it an instance of a point in 3d?  If so, then getZ is probably getting the 3rd dim and not what you'd want here.

Comment: I think this is a 3D solution. (Top tip: Write the simplest thing first. Then adapt it. Possibly keep the original solution in a separate method and call that.) @Jere `Vector` doesn't appear to be `java.util.Vector` but a 3D Vector. @sofend `axis` appears to refer to one of the X/Y/Z axises. Can't be bothered to look through this in detail given the state of the question, but straight away, if converting to the cited but not quoted Wikipedia article, it looks as if `a` should be `-coeffs`. Also confusing using the same letters for different things.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline yes `Vector` is a homemade class. Position is another vector, but I only want the closest point on the (x,z) plane, so that's why I'm not using the y coordinate. But I don't see how -coeff instead of coeff for a should change anything, a can be negative or positive

Answer (score 0):

If you stay in vector representation it may be easier.
I have an example code but only in C++ (and Direct3D):

```
D3DXVECTOR3 ProjectOnLine (const D3DXVECTOR3 &point,
                           const D3DXVECTOR3 &linePoint,
                           const D3DXVECTOR3 &lineUnityDir)
{
  float t = D3DXVec3Dot(&(point-linePoint), &lineUnityDir);
  return linePoint + lineUnityDir*t;
}
```

If I understand you then your parameters can be used like this:

```
D3DXVECTOR3 point = position;
D3DXVECTOR3 linePoint = axis;
D3DXVECTOR3 lineUnityDir = D3DXVECTOR3(1, a, 0)/sqrt(1+a*a);
```